# How Modbus RTU Slave differentiates between read and write command by Modbus master?

Tags: modbus

I have started a Modbus RTU Slave implementation on STM32G071 micro controller.
I have started with a `Read Holding Register` function code.
I want to understand how write operation occurs. Please correct my understanding.

1. Modbus Holding Register Read.
   Message by Master (in Hex):

   SlaveID Function_Code AddressHighbyte AddressLowbyte QuantityHighbyte QuantityLowbyte CRCHighbyte CRCLowbyte: 01 03 00 04 00 03 07 58
2. Modbus Holding Register Read response by Modbus RTU Slave (in Hex):

`SlaveID Function_Code QuantityBytes Value1HighByte Value1LowByte Value2HighByte Value2LowByte Value3HighByte Value3LowByte CRCHighbyte CRCLowbyte: 01 03 06 12e3 45ef 63de 58 BA`

Holding register function code is a read/write function. How slave will differentiate between `read and write commands`? My understanding is:

1. Using Function code 03 We can only read analog register(s).
2. To write holding register, Master actually uses `Function code 06` and `Function code 16`
3. But point#2 is contradictory to my experience. We generally configure analog output registers with `Function code 3` in PLC/DCS.

Please guide me.

Finally a query on CRC check by Slave device when received Write command:

1. Should slave check `CRC` received first before processing?

Comment: Answers: 1)yes, 2)yes, 3)your experience seems to be incorrect,  maybe you can explain how exactly you acquired that experience, where and which PLCs/DCSs you are referring to, 1bis)yes. It might be a good idea to take a look at a Modbus library and see what's under its hood, try for instance [libmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/). There are also many implementations for microcontrollers, google around and you'll find them.

Comment: @MarcosG. Thanks for your comments. Yes you may be true with point#3. Even i want to know. Ex. In DCS (Modbus master). I configure a tag's modbus register as 40005 and use this for forcing value on the Slave Device. Is it like at the backend the modbus master converts to function code 06 or 16? In the mean time i will also explore libmodbus.

Comment: @MarcosG.Now i understood, Please correct me if i am wrong.For modbus write, Modbus master uses function code 06 or function code 16. But its register Number will be in range of  `40k` example `40005`. Thankyou veru much. As a user, never thought of this.

Comment: To your first comment: yes, the PLC or DCS is using function code 06 or 16 behind the scenes. And the 40k offset is only used to distinguish between holding and input registers; as you know the 40k offset is absent from the Modbus frames, it's just a convention (agreement between parties).

Comment: Yes. @MarcosG.. Thankyou very much. Concept and basic cleared.